# i am unable to get the title of the web page in the selenium code

Tags: selenium-webdriver, junit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxKiB.jpg)i am unable to get the title of the web page using internet explorer on the latest version of windows 10. kindly let me know what is wrong with the code.

```
static WebDriver driver;
String actualTitle;

@Test
public void test() {
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
    System.out.println("ActualTitle is :" + actualTitle );
}
@BeforeClass
public static void Beforeclass() {
   driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
}
@AfterClass
public static void Afterclass() {
  driver.quit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make your driver static.  You also don't need your setup and tear-down methods to be static.

You may need to wait for the page to load by checking the DOM state.

In some cases you may also check for document.readyState == 'interactive' as well - it all depends on what you're aiming for so here is [one doc about it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState)

```
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> condition = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            Object obj = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("var result = document.readyState; return (result == 'complete');");

            if (obj == null) {
                return false;
            }
            return obj.toString().equals("true");
        }
    };
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(condition);
```

Comment: the problem with the code is that it returns the value as "webdriver" and not the title; i am attaching screen shot , kindly help me out.

Comment: the image uploaded is in link highlighted in the question above